# matrix power after multiplying row by factor

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

Consider a Matrix $M$ with non-negative entries and it's power $M^n$. Assume we know every entry of $M^n$ denoted by $m_{ij;n}$.
Now we multiply the $i$-th row of $M$ by a positive factor $\alpha$ which yields $M'$.
What can we say about the relation between $m_{ij;n}$ and $m'_{ij;n}$?

$m'_{ij;n} \geq \alpha m_{ij;n}$ should hold, but can we say more than this?

Does the following work:

(1) $m'_{ii;n} = \sum_k m'_{ik;1} m'_{ki;n-1} \geq m'_{ii;1} m'_{ii;n-1} \geq \cdots \geq m'^n_{ii;1} \geq \alpha^n m^n_{ii;1}$

I also thought along those lines: multiplying a row can be seen as multiplying by an appropriate diagonal matrix $D$. Hence the question becomes: How do entries of $(DM)^n$ correspond to entries of $M^n$?

Comment: Unless you are assuming all nonnegative coefficients, even your inequalities won't be valid. Your update has little linear-algebraic meaning (your expression with $DM$ is correct, but $D$ does not commute with $M$), so don't expect much to hold here in general.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen so does (1) hold under the assumptions I made ($M$ has non-negative entries, $\alpha > 0$)?

Comment: But still (1) would not give me a relation between $m_{ij;n}$ and $m'_{ij;n}$...